# Функция открыть с помощью, получить адрес открываемого файла на С++ без консоли

Tags: c++, visual-c++, glfw

Заканчиваю программу для мгновенного доступа к звуку по нажатию на клавишу.

Хочу чтоб по нажатию на файл сохраненного проекта, этот файл открывался в моей программе, но ка реализовать чтобы программа получила путь к файлу?

Если бы я не отключил консоль то можно было бы так и это был бы ответ,

```
int main(int count, char *arg[])
{
   // arg[0] Адрес программы
   // arg[1] то что нужно файл через который программа была открыта
   // или адрес на то что пытались открыть с помощью этой параграммы
}
```

но я отключил консоль и через аргументы теперь это не реализуется.

консоль отключил с помощью следующих настроек.

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

так вот использую С++ оконная библиотека glfw с отключенной консолью открывать файл с помощью моей программы.

или хотя бы скажите как такая технология называется
Например раньше я не знал что перетаскивание файлов в окно называется Drag-and-drop, по этому поиск был сложен.

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если кому надо будет. организовал так. Благодаря ответу.

```
    std::string arg = GetCommandLineA();
    std::vector<std::string> Masiv;

    bool tumbler = 0;
    std::string Stemp = "";
    while(arg.size() > 0)
    {

        if(arg[0] == '"')
        {
            tumbler = !tumbler;
            if(tumbler == 0)
            {
                Masiv.push_back(Stemp);
                Stemp = "";
            }
        }

        if(tumbler)
        {
            if(arg[0] != '"')
                Stemp+=arg[0];

        }

        arg.erase(arg.begin()+0);
    }


if(Masiv.size()>1)
    Open(Masiv[1]);
```

Comment: Вот просто интересно - кто-то понял **по заголовку** о чем речь? Повторю, чтоб не листать - *"Функция открыть с помощью на С++ без консоли"*? Что открыть? С помощью чего? а ведь в первую очередь смотришь именно на заголовок...

Comment: если взять какой то файл кликнуть по нем открыть с помощью, выбрать нашу написанную программу, она откреститься но как узнать адрес того файла в программе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут проблема в том, что при установке параметра Subsystem в "Windows" вид точки входа изменяется. Точка входа по умолчанию для приложения Win32 будет иметь [такой вид](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/winmain--the-application-entry-point):

```
INT WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR lpCmdLine, INT nCmdShow)
```

т.е. командная строка передается третьим параметром. Если вы устанавливаете Subsystem=Windows, но при этом принудительно задаете точку входа main, то аргументы будут обрабатываться неправильно. Лучше сделать так:

1. Сбросить параметр Entry point в значение по умолчанию
2. Вместо функции main создать в проекте функцию WinMain с указанным выше прототипом.

Тогда вы сможете получить доступ к переданным аргументам командной строки через параметр lpCmdLine, который является указателем на строку char* (если параметров несколько, вы можете разделить строку через strtok). Другой вариант - использовать функцию [GetCommandLine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinea), которая позволяет получить командную строку из любой функции.

Answer (score 1):

На Windows это делается через реестр (registry). В двух словах - регистрируется название программы, к этому значению привязывается команда, которая должна выполняться при открытии файла. Затем регистрируется расширение файла и к нему привязывается зарегистрированная программа.

Программно это можно сделать либо напрямую работая с windows API (или через библиотеку), либо же через какие-то программы - например, [**assoc**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/assoc).

Вручную это делается через свойства файла, или опять же прямо записывая значения в реестр через **regedit**.

---

Ключи в реестре

В `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\<расширение файла>` регистрируется расширение. Там полно их, можно сделать по примеру существующих. Эта ветка реестра будет доступна только для текущего пользователя. Чтобы зарегистрировать для всех пользователей системы нужно использовать `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` вместо `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.

В `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\<название программы>\shell\open\command`
 нужно записать путь к исполняемому файлу и передать в него первый аргумент (открываемый файл). Например, так `c:\app.exe "%1"`.

Затем создается ключ `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\<расширение файла>\OpenWithProgIds\<название программы>` чтобы связать расширение с программой.

Если каких-то ключей нет, то их нужно создать.

Comment: Да но я другое имел ввиду, именно после того как мы кликнули на файл и открылась наша программа как в нашей программе получить адрес файла, который по мути вызвал кликом по нему нашу программу.

Comment: @ЮрійПисанка в Windows этот путь будет а списке аргументов функции `main(int argc, char** argv)`. Путь к нему будет `argv[1]`. Только там есть ограничения на размер пути, на кодировку и прочее.

Comment: При отключении консоли эти аргументы больше не хранят нужной информации по этому и вопрос задал.

Comment: @ЮрійПисанка что вы имеете в виду под «отключением консоли»?

Comment: Я модифицировал вопрос и добавил скриншоты как я отключил консоль, но я уже получил работоспособный ответ. Спасибо за участвие.